# Inverse Fourier transform of $\omega^{2k}\hat{f}(\omega)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

While calculating a Fourier inverse, I get the following expression
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \omega^{2k} \hat{f}(\omega) e^{-iwx}dw$$

where $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I though of taking the inverse the inverse Fourier transform of $w^{2k}$, call it $g$, and then the expression becomes

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{g}(\omega) \hat{f}(\omega) e^{-iwx}dw
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \widehat{g*f} (\omega) e^{-iwx}dw\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&=g*f
\end{align}

But the inverse Fourier transform of $w^{2k}$ turns out to be unbounded.

> Is there some other way to calculate the integral? I am expecting it in terms of expression of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

The factor $\omega^{2 k}$ in

$$ \omega^{2 k} e^{-i \omega x} = (i \frac{d}{dx})^{2k} e^{-i \omega x }$$

can be interchanged with integration, if $\hat f$ is smooth with compact support, eg.,
$$\int \hat f(\omega ) \ \omega^{2 k} e^{-i \omega x} d \omega  = (-1)^k \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{2k} \ \int \hat f(\omega ) \   e^{-i \omega x} d \omega $$

Comment: You're uisng $k$ and $n$ interchangeably.

Comment: @Ronald Thank you. This is a nice trick. As Mark pointed out, $n$ in your answer should be $k$.

Comment: --and the name is Roland. Directly typing TeX with text of 5 point resolution is a random process.  But ist not a trick. the correspondence  of differential equations and algebraic equatiion by Fourier transfom was the kick start of modern mathematics and mathematical physics parallel to